# Windows IIS Server stops Django processes after 2 minutes

Tags: python, django, iis, windows-server-2012, ip-camera

I have django project that provides a IP Camera streaming and recording system that is using Python OpenCV so it needs to run processes for a long time, maybe one hour or more. However, the Windows IIS Server stops the processes after about 2 minutes.

Is There any way to prevent IIS from doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Please set these items and check result then.

Select site-> advance setting-> Preload enable=true.
[image]

Select application pool-> advance setting-> start mode=always running.
Idle Time-out=0.
Regular Time Interval=0.

[image]

Then reset IIS.

Comment: I've already done that before but still it kills the process which survives longer than 2 minutes.
@user:14162739

Comment: Do you mean that the process was killed by IIS server? If so, you need to check event viewer. It will show you error message that why process was killed.

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure IIS kills them. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please check event viewer.

Comment: I checked the event viewer but couldn't find any useful data about IIS. I ran the localserver of django project on the windows server and observe the logs all processes run successfully and survive until I stop them. But when I run them on IIS they cannot last more than 2 minutes.

Comment: It is difficult to deal with it without more information. And according to your description, I cannot find out issue. Please create a support ticket from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/). They can open a remote session with you to find the problem more easily.